# Kotlin spring security config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kotlin

After upgrading to Kotlin `1.0.0-beta-3595` from `1.0.0-beta-242` the following code does not compile:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity)
{
    http.addFilterBefore(AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authorization/**", "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
}
```

Error returned is:

```
SecurityAssembly.kt: (48, 65): Unresolved reference: permitAll
```

**Edit:**

The signature of the permitAll method, which is from the popular Spring Security framework is:

```
public ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry permitAll() {
    return access(permitAll);
}
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you provide the function signature for permitAll (before upgrading)?

Comment: @mfulton26 ah, yes of course. added thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Kotlin 1.0-beta3595, and has been [logged here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10285).